# checkbox not getting unchecked in wicket

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff

I have a checkgroup and on selecting a checkbox in the group I want to get the number of selected/checked check boxes. 
By the below code, I am able to get the selected number of checkboxes but on unchecking or removing the selection, i see that its still selected.
Example : I have selected 2 now I get 2 string selected.
Now I unselect one checkbox, even now i get 2 strings selected. While I expect one string to be checked.

The code is given below:

```
final CheckGroup myGroup = new CheckGroup("group", new ArrayList()) {
    @Override
    protected Collection<String> convertValue(String[] values) throws ConversionException {
        Collection<String> myCollection = super.convertValue(values);
        checkedString.addAll(myCollection);
        HashMap<Integer, String> myTempList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (String myString : checkedString) {
            myTempList.put(myString.getSystemId(), myString);
        }
        checkedString.clear();
        for (Entry<Integer, String> myEntry : myTempList.entrySet()) {
            checkedString.add(myEntry.getValue());
        }
        return checkedString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(Collection newSelection) {
        newSelection = checkedString;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
};


add(myForm);
myForm.add(myGroup);
```

Comment: I am using wicket 1.4.19

Comment: I don't get your code in the `onSelectionChanged`. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I wanted to get the number of selectedOrders, but its not required now.

Comment: Your vision is correct but your approach is wrong. Use ajax to implement  onSelectionChanged method .

Answer (score 0):

Add a behavior to your component

```
sampleChckbox.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick"){
  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
 //perform your operation here       
}
```

This method will fire an Ajax request on "onClick" event; which will update your backend logic at runtime

**edit :**

To be very specific to CheckGroup class use the AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior

[`AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.html) is the behavior to use with `CheckGroup`s and `RadioGroup`s. If you used an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` with the `onchange` event, you'd run into [this bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html) with IE 
. `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` handles this properly, [adding `onclick` event handlers](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.8/org/apache/wicket/ajax/form/AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior.java#63) to each of the `Check`s in the `CheckGroup`.

As a side note, what Igor stated in that mail, is that `CheckBox` can be replaced with `AjaxCheckBox`, not `Check`. `AjaxCheckBox` is nothing more than a convenience subclass of  `CheckBox` with an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick")`, as [the sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxCheckBox.java) show.

Comment: I have not used checkbox, I have only used CheckGroupSelector, CheckGroup

Comment: pardon ; what is your doubt ?